# I am trying to find the index value with item- attached with it `item-0, item-1, item-2, item-3`

Tags: angular, indexing, repeater

I am trying to find the index **value** with item- attached within `item-0, item-1, item-2, item-3`, if anyone can help with a solution for this.

json:

```
"ingredients": {
      "item-0": {
        "amount": "30",
        "measurement": "g",
        "item": "455"
      },
      "item-1": {
        "amount": "10",
        "measurement": "oz",
        "item": "455"
      }
      "item-2": {
        "amount": "1",
        "measurement": "lb",
        "item": "455"
      }
      "item-3": {
        "amount": "3",
        "measurement": "tsp",
        "item": "455"
      }
    },'
```

angular:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of recipe.ingredients; let i = index;">
    <li>{{recipe[i].amount}}</li>
    <li>{{recipe[i].measurement}}</li>
    <li>{{recipe[i].item}}</li>
</ul>
```

I can only return the **index value** as a number but I would need return it as `item-[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const keys = Object.keys(ingredients);
console.log(keys); // [ 'item-1', 'item-2', 'item-3'] 

// Getting the numbers from each key
const numbers = keys.map((key) => key.split('-')[1]);
console.log(numbers); // ['1', '2', '3'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin Pipe KeyValue to iterate on an Object:
https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe.

Then you can use `item.key` (to get 'item-1', 'item-2', 'item-3') and `item.value` to access the data:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of recipe.ingredients | keyvalue">
  <li>{{item.key}}</li>
  <li>{{item.value.amount}}</li>
  <li>{{item.value.measurement}}</li>
  <li>{{item.value.item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uavxyr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html